# Exclude custom options from shipping and tax calculations

Tags: shipping, tax, custom-options

Is there any way to exclude custom options with prices from shipping and tax calculations without the need for a custom module? Just seeing if anyone out there has done this without too much effort.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You have a shirt (25$), you can (custom option) add a print for 15$ and you don't want that this lowers the shipping, beacause there is free shipping if you buy more than 30$? I don't think so, that this is possible out of the box . And I thinks this is not easy to implement, because the custom option is added to the price and the price is used for the calculations

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are correct, it's not built in anywhere. I did some custom code to modify the tax calculations and works great - thanks.

Comment: Will you share the ideas with us? And Answer your own question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the shipping method calculations, I looped through quoteItems and called a helper (getItemOptionsPriceTotal). The helper defined what is billable and what is not. Then, I set the item price in the quoter to the item price minus the generated options price from getItemOptionsPriceTotal. Bit awkward but works... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on this, I overrode the `_totalBaseCalculation` function of `Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Subtotal`. In that function, I called my (custom) helper `getItemOptionsPriceTotal` which got the total options prices for that item. Inside `Subtotal.php`, I then subtracted the item tax price from `$taxable` before that is set with `$item->setTaxableAmount`.

As far as the shipping part goes, I did something similar but a bit different (using custom shipping module). I subtracted the options price from the item base price as so: `$item->setPrice($item->getPrice() - $optionsPrice);` before the shipping rate was calculated. This seemed to work...

Answer (score 0):

No :)

I worked with VAT in Magento for quite some time, did some research on what modules are already there, but this is not standard, nor I could find another module.

Another nasty issue with VAT is it seems Argentinian law.

Comment: Thanks, I did wind up adding custom logic to add/subtract to shipping logic.